# What is the PDE corresponding to this weak formulation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

Consider a flow $(\mu_t)_{t\ge 0}$ such that

1. every $\mu_t$ is a probability on $\mathbb R_+$;
2. $\mu_0(dx) = \rho(x) \, dx$ with $\rho$ being a probability density (as nice as possible) on $\mathbb R_+$;
3. For any test function $f:\mathbb R_+ \to\mathbb R$ (smooth and of compact support), it holds
   $$\int_{\mathbb R_+}f(x)\mu_t(dx)=\int_{\mathbb R_+}f(x)\mu_0(dx) + \frac 12\int_0^t \int_{(0,\infty)^2}\frac{f'(x)-f'(y)}{x-y}\mu_s(d x)\mu_s(d y) \, ds,\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

If we assume that $\mu_t$ admits the decomposition

$$\mu_t(dx) = m(t)\delta_0(dx) + p(t,x) \, dx, \quad  \text{where } m(t)=1-\int_0^\infty p(t,x) \, dx \text{ is the mass concentrated on } 0,$$

then we see by differentiating with respect to $t$

$$\int_0^\infty \big(f(x)-f(0)\big) \partial_tp(t,x) \, dx = \frac 12 \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{f'(x)-f'(y)}{x-y}p(t,x)p(t,y) \, dx \, dy.\tag{$\ast$} $$

What is the PDE corresponding to $(\ast)$? Combined with which conditions?

An immediate observation is $p(0,\cdot)=\rho$. Can we guess $p(t,0)=0$?